# How many tables can be mapped in hibernate mapping.?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring, nhibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate and am using xml file for mapping. I want to map more than 8 tables, is it possible or not ?

I am using mysql for DB. In all that mapping examples they use maximum 3 tables in mapping.  If I change the value in one table that has to reflect it on to next one.

For Example I am giving the Username in my Employee Table and use that one in my login table.  If I am mapping 2 tables it means, the username in employee table can  automatically update to my login table.  Is this correct ?

And how many tables am I able to map in single xml file.

Comment: You mean you want to use username as foreign key in multiple tables? If thats what you mean, then you can definitely do it

Answer (score 0):

A hibernate component may be your solution.  Also hibernate definitions can be in separate files and hibernate will figure it out.

https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+components

Comment: Thanks for your response dude.but in components we do that in same table.But am using the employee as separate table and login as separate table .

Comment: Components are good for any group of repeated elements like updated date, update user, etc...

Comment: that means by using components for save the values in 2 tables at same time? right,but in examples whatever i saw all of them used in same table only, thats why am confusing.

Comment: It will not save in two tables at the same time.  It just allows you to use the same definition in two tables.  The fields would have to be in both tables and save would be called on both objects.